# kafka streams doesn't start up

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I couldn't start my Kafka streams application. I was able to when I was depending on Confluent Kafka cloud, but when I did the switch to Kafka locally on docker it doesn't start anymore.

docker-compose:

```yaml
# https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html
# https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images

version: "3"

services:

  zookeeper:
    container_name: local-zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    hostname: zookeeper
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181

  kafka:
    container_name: local-kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
    hostname: kafka
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1

  schema-registry:
    container_name: local-schema-registry
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    hostname: schema-registry
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        # install jq
        curl -sL https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64 -o /usr/local/bin/jq && chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/jq
        # start
        /etc/confluent/docker/run

  schema-registry-ui:
    container_name: local-schema-registry-ui
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui:latest
    depends_on:
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    hostname: schema-registry-ui
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - PROXY=true

  kafka-rest:
    container_name: local-kafka-rest
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: kafka-rest
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS=http://kafka-rest:8082
      - KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME=kafka-rest

  kafka-ui:
    container_name: local-kafka-ui
    image: landoop/kafka-topics-ui:latest
    depends_on:
      - kafka-rest
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    hostname: kafka-ui
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL=http://kafka-rest:8082
      - PROXY=true

  # https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/4.1.3-post/docs/tutorials/docker-compose.yml#L85
  ksql-server:
    container_name: local-ksql-server
    # TODO update 5.5.1
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.4.2
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    hostname: ksql-server
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:29092
      - KSQL_LISTENERS=http://ksql-server:8088
      - KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID=local-ksql-server

  ksql-cli:
    container_name: local-ksql-cli
    # TODO update 5.5.1
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.4.2
    depends_on:
      - ksql-server
    hostname: ksql-cli
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  # distributed mode
  kafka-connect:
    container_name: local-kafka-connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    hostname: kafka-connect
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:29092
      - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-connect
      - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
      - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=local-connect-group
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=local-connect-configs
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS=10000
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=local-connect-offsets
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=local-connect-status
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java
    volumes:
      - "./local/connect/data:/data"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        # install unzip
        apt-get update && apt-get install unzip -y
        # install plugin
        unzip /data/jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-*.zip 'jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-*/lib/*' -d /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-spooldir/
        mv /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-spooldir/*/lib/* /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-spooldir
        ls -la /usr/share/java
        # setup spooldir plugin
        mkdir -p /tmp/error /tmp/finished
        # start
        /etc/confluent/docker/run

  kafka-connect-ui:
    container_name: local-kafka-connect-ui
    image: landoop/kafka-connect-ui:latest
    depends_on:
      - kafka-connect
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    hostname: kafka-connect-ui
    networks:
      - local_kafka_network
    environment:
      - CONNECT_URL=http://kafka-connect:8083

networks:
  local_kafka_network:
```

Main method:

```java
package io.confluent.developer.time.solution;

import io.confluent.developer.StreamsUtils;
import io.confluent.developer.avro.ElectronicOrder;
import io.confluent.developer.time.TopicLoader;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class StreamsTimestampExtractor {

    static class OrderTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {
        @Override
        public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record, long partitionTime) {
            ElectronicOrder order = (ElectronicOrder)record.value();
            System.out.println("Extracting time of " + order.getTime() + " from " + order);
            return order.getTime();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final Properties streamsProps = StreamsUtils.loadProperties();
        streamsProps.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "extractor-windowed-streams");

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final String inputTopic = streamsProps.getProperty("extractor.input.topic");
        final String outputTopic = streamsProps.getProperty("extractor.output.topic");
        final Map<String, Object> configMap = StreamsUtils.propertiesToMap(streamsProps);

        final SpecificAvroSerde<ElectronicOrder> electronicSerde =
                StreamsUtils.getSpecificAvroSerde(configMap);

        final KStream<String, ElectronicOrder> electronicStream =
                builder.stream(inputTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), electronicSerde)
                        .withTimestampExtractor(new OrderTimestampExtractor()))
                        .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Incoming record - key " +key +" value " + value));

        electronicStream.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(1)))
                .aggregate(() -> 0.0,
                        (key, order, total) -> total + order.getPrice(),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()))
                .toStream()
                .map((wk, value) -> KeyValue.pair(wk.key(),value))
                .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Outgoing record - key " +key +" value " + value))
                .to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsProps);
        TopicLoader.runProducer();
        kafkaStreams.start();

    }
}
```

Running the code in my machine produces records but exits immediately:
[image]

Note that I was able to process the continuous stream of data when I was running this exact code with confluent Kafka cloud.

To reproduce locally, all you need is to get the code from this [confluent tutorial](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/hands-on-time-concepts/), modify the properties file to point to the local Kafka broker, and use the docker-compose I provided for setting up Kafka.

Comment: Please show your full producer and stream properties and the Gradle command

Comment: Indeed! The issue was in my properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a shutdown hook and uncaught exception handler helped me diagnose and fix the issue:

```java
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsProps);
        TopicLoader.runProducer();
        kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(e -> {
            log.error("unhandled streams exception, shutting down.", e);
            return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.SHUTDOWN_APPLICATION;
        });

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            log.info("Runtime shutdown hook, state={}", kafkaStreams.state());
            if (kafkaStreams.state().isRunningOrRebalancing()) {
                log.info("Shutting down started.");
                kafkaStreams.close(Duration.ofMinutes(2));
                log.info("Shutting down completed.");
            }
        }));
        kafkaStreams.start();
```

Turns out I’ve configured a replication factor of 1 in the broker while in my properties file I had 3, so the exception was: Caused by: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.`
So the solution for me was to decrease the `replication.factor` from 3 to 1 in my properties file.